# How does a quill stem without a front bolt work?

Tags: road-bike, handlebars, stem

Looking at quill stems I noticed this rather curious one and I couldn't imagine how it secured the handlebars without an apparent bolt. Any ideas?

[more images](http://www.velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=1b643cfc-b7cd-40bb-ac50-a67815dcd066&Enum=102)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At 10 o'clock there is a wedge that holds the handlebar. Taking off the plastic cap at the end of the stem reveals the bolts for tightening the stem and handlebar.

Comment: I see, [opened up](http://www.velosaloon.com/shop/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/800x534/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/d/s/dsc_0206_1_12.jpg).

Comment: it is a nice design, I quite like the columbus stems but this has a certain class to it.